# Export user rights into a SQL file for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, backup

I would like to know if there is a query to export the user rights `select insert grant` and so on, to a SQL file.

I managed to get the list of the Grants:

```
Select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_PRIVILEGES
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to Script User and Role Object Permissions in SQL Server](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/2002/object-permission-scripts/)

Might also be of interest:
[How to transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246133)